# Signing the application with our CA

Tags: tizen

Is it possible to sign the application with our own CA certificate and installing the signed application on the device

I have created a CA certificate with .CER format  and i tried to install but device not accepting to install the certficate but when i checked about phone option  in device there is a option like user certificates

if it possible can any one give the detailed procedure of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this procedure step by step , You will get the solution

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development--mobile-1441

Comment: @user2218591 was asking about tizen certificate process, not ios. Check question's tag.